# Error handling in python if file written with int instead of string

Tags: python-3.x, list, class, error-handling, text-files

I have a code that works and have a simple question. If I were to change the text-file from strings to integer I want to error handle that. Is it possible? I only get error-warning when I change the integers to strings however I want it to work for changing strings to integer. For example if I change "Football" into a integer I want to get a error-warning. I then want to create an error-handling to print for example: "Something is wrong inside the textfile"

```
textfile:
Football # 8-9 # Pitch
Basketball # 9-10 # Gym
Lunch # 11-12 # Home
Reading # 13-14 # Library


from pprint import pprint
class Activity:
    def __init__(self, name, start_time, end_time, location):
        self.name = str(name)
        self.start = int(start_time)
        self.end = int(end_time)
        self.location = str(location)

 
def read_file(filename):
    activities = []
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            activity, time, location = line.strip().split(' # ')
            start, end = time.split('-')
            activities.append(Activity(activity, start, end, location))
    return activities

activities = read_file('sample.txt')
pprint(activities)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if a string is an integer by using [isnumeric](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/isnumeric).

So let's change the input file to:

```
Football # 8-9 # Pitch
Basketball # 9-10 # Gym
Lunch # 11-12 # Home
3 # 13-14 # Library
```

Now we want to verify the name, for which we will write a validator:

```
class Activity:
    def __init__(self, name, start_time, end_time, location):
        self.name = self.validate_name(name)
        self.start = int(start_time)
        self.end = int(end_time)
        self.location = location

    def validate_name(self, name):
        if name.isnumeric():
            raise TypeError(f"The name: {name!r}, is not a string, please check your input file.")
        return name

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<{type(self).__name__}, (name={self.name}, start={self.start}, end={self.end}, loc={self.location})>"
```

Which results in a `TypeError`:

```
 line 13, in validate_name
    raise TypeError(f"The name: {name!r}, is not a string, please check your input file.")
TypeError: The name: '3', is not a string, please check your input file.
```

Note that your input is already a string, so there was no need to use `str(name)` and `str(location)`.

---

#### Edit

The above solution only verifies if the entire name is an integer. For a solution that checks if the input is using valid characters we can use the `re` module in python and the method:

```
import re

def validate_input(self, name):
    regex = re.compile('\d')
    if regex.match(name):
        raise TypeError(f"The name: {name!r}, contains an integer, please check your input file.")
    return name
```

This will break whenever there is an integer in the input name. The previous solution would continue on inputs such as: `Football 3`, `3 Football`. This solution would raise an error.

You can try out the regex expression for yourself on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/B3wLL1/2)

Comment: I do not understand the question, if you mean that there is no other way than catching the error, you are right. But the class is raising the exception, so if you want to change the message you can do that in the `validate_name` method.

Comment: Thank you for the help!! I tried the method it worked. But one question: is this method only working for the specific example that I wrote or is it a general method that can be used in other examples

Comment: It is a general approach, I verify if the string input is an integer (numeric) and if so I manually `raise` the error. Alternatively you can check if all inputs are in the alphabet using [isalpha](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/isalpha), instead. Note that you cannot use 'white spaces' in the activy name then, such as `drinking water`.

Comment: I see!!! Are there making it possible for spaces too? Like your example

Comment: If I want it to work for: drinking water, how can I make this possible?

Comment: Because I have another textfile that uses spaces and I want the same thing to work but it doesnt, thank you for your time :)

Comment: The current solution would work for that, since it is only checking for integers.

Comment: Thank you sir appreciate it! It doesnt have to be anything complicated preferably simple if possible

Comment: I updated my answer, there is no also a solution that simply checks if there is a digit in the name and then if so, it will raise an error.

Comment: Thanks sir I will try it

Comment: unfortunately it did not work for me, but thanks anyway :))

Comment: As I said im using another textfile for the same principle. It gave me error when the textfile was written right. AttributeError: 'Act' object has no attribute 'validate_name'

Comment: That error means that there no `validate_name` method in the `Act` object. Did you add the method to the class?

Comment: Yes I did! Then I wrote: self.name = self.validate_name(name)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225437/discussion-between-thymen-and-carl-erik-pettersson).